# Gradle withSourcesJar as library not working

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I have a current Gradle, Java 11, project that I intent to use as a library with a set of general purpose functions for another apps.

I'm using the Gradle function:

```
java{
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

To build a `.jar` with the source and JavaDoc included. However when I import that `.jar` into another app (via Gradle implementation) all the non java SDK dependencies in the .jar library fails with a message of the style:

```
Package 'x' is declared in module 'y', but module 'z' does not read it
```

Even though that all the required dependencies are already implemented (via Gradle as well) in the host app.

The part that puzzle me more, is that if I build the library jar, as a simple plain `.jar`(meaning source code but no Javadoc) the library works smoothly when implemented in other apps, it only fails when I try to build it as a `withSourcesJar()`.

So any help that could point me on what I doing wring in the `withSourcesJar()` or what extra configuration should I add, would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the code from the gradle project implementing the library ?
From what you are telling, i think you are adding the wrong jar as a dependency, you are not supposed to add the -sources.jar as a dependency